# Integral of $x\sin^2 (x^2)$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the integral of $y = x\sin^2 (x^2)$. Can someone help please? I've tried converting it to $x(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x^2))$ and using integration by parts but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: First let $u=x^{2}$ and notice that $\sin^{2}(u)=\frac{1-\cos(2u)}{2}$

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it's just a one trick that makes the question so much simpler.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$x\left(\dfrac12−\dfrac12\cos(2x^2)\right)=\dfrac{x}2-\dfrac18\times4x\cos(2x^2)$

From there $4x\cos(2x^2)$ is of the form $u'\cos u$, and therefore is easy to integrate

Answer (score 0):

1) $x \sin^2(x^2)dx = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x^2)d x^2$

2) $\sin^2 t = \frac{1 - \cos 2t}{2}$

Comment: What does $dx^2$ mean?

Comment: Yeah I didn't get that either

Comment: Poor notation. He made the substitution $u=x^2$ so that he has $\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 x^2 \, \mathrm{d}(x^2)$ or $\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 u \, \mathrm{d}u$.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did: $\frac{1}{2} d(x^2)  =x dx$. What's wrong with this notation?